# Watch a partial WMV - partially downloaded in emule?

Tags: encoding, windows-media-player, wmv, p2p, emule

How can I watch a partial WMV, partially downloaded in eMule?

I know it can be done for MPGs.

Comment: Make sure to enable the option `Options⇨Files⇨Miscellaneous⇨Try to download preview chunks first`. It will give higher priority to the first and last chunks which are need to (properly) preview video files. A truncated video may not play very well or at all, even if you have the beginning but not the end.

Answer (score 1):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) can usually handle "broken" files.

There are various (newer even) third-party adaptations, front-ends around.
http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/projects.html

The beginning of the file (at the least) needs to be somewhat complete.
Otherwise, so long as the file is not locked (read lock), MPlayer can usually do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

VLC can usually play partially complete or corrupted files, though it depends how complete the file actually is.

Comment: I have used VLC and my experience has been that as with WMP. It played partially downloaded MPGs, but not WMVs